# Join two files and get the matching records on shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix

I have two files both files are separated by delimiter we need to join these two files and send the matching records to out_file on the first file key column is 1st column and in the second file 3rd column is the key column and on out_file i  need all the columns from first file and only  6th columns from second file

Sample files

Note:Original files has 90+ records and both the files are unsorted)

File1:

```
Username| Status| Managername
4115    |  Open  | X
234      | Expired |Y
```

File2:

```
Id| Name| Username| type| role| Access
1| User1| 4115| primary| connect| Never
2|User|432|Nonuser|conect|Never
```

OutputFile

```
Username| Status| Managername| Access
4115    |  Open  | X |Never
```

I have tried this but this is giving all the records from both the files:

```
join -a 2  -t "|" -1 1 -2 3 file1 file2>out_file
```

Comment: Can you just `cat file1 file2 | grep 'some string' > out.txt`? Is this a csv file??

Comment: yes this is .csv file and i need to send  the matching records from file 1 and file2 to out_file so i guess this will not work(grep 'some string')?

Comment: So does the presented code work? You did not ask any question.

Comment: You did not write a question or tell what's wrong with your code. Please [edit] your question and copy&paste example input files, actual output and expected output *as text*. Explaining your code might also help to understand the problem.

Comment: Please do the [tour] and read about [ask]. Please also click [edit] and add representative sample input files and corresponding output files. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry this is my first time posting so could not make it clearly I have edited my question now

Comment: checkout `tcsv`. It can be installed with `cargo install tcsv`

Comment: Input files have to be sorted. Assuming `bash` or `ksh` (don't know about `zsh`), you can do `join -a 2  -t "|" -1 1 -2 3 <( sort file1) <(sort file2)>out_file` (I think). Good luck.

Comment: Using an example that produces more than one line of output, not counting the heading, would be better. Are the spaces important? Would `4115|Open|X|Never` be OK? Please clarify in your question if you want to print only lines with "Username" numbers that are present in both files. In `File1`, is there always at least one space between the "Username" number and the `|`?

Comment: Yes this 4115|Open|X|Never would be okay for output, i want to print only username with numbers if the username matches for file1 and file2  Access column need to be joined to the outfile for that username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F' *[|] *' 'FNR==NR { a[$3]=$6; next } $1 in a { print $0 " | " a[$1] }' File2 File1
```

prints

```
Username| Status| Managername | Access
4115    |  Open  | X | Never
```

Note that `File2` is specified first.

**Explanation:**

- `-F' *[|] *'` = set `|` with optional spaces before and after as input field separator
- `FNR==NR` = condition that is true for the first file only (file record number == total record number)
- `a[$3]=$6` = store 3rd field (from `File2`) as key with 6th field as value in array `a`
- `next` = skip further processing, continue with next line. This makes sure all following code is executed for the second and following files only.
- `$1 in a` = condition if the 1st field is present as a key in `a`
- `print $0 " | " a[$1]` print the current input line (from `File1`) followed by a separator and the value from `a` matching the key

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking the check mark. It would be good to improve the question anyway as suggested in comments.